# Is it possible to append new modules to existing SonarQube project?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have created Jenkins job which will run UT + SonarQube scan.
The folder structure is I have module under which different components on which UT and Sonar scan will run.
Folder structure:
M1/M1_C1
M1/M1_C2
M1/M1C3

M2/M2_C1
M2/M2_C2

In code i am passing sonar properties as below:

```
echo 'sonar.projectKey='M1.sonar > sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectName='M1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectVersion=1.0'

echo 'sonar.host.url='$SONAR_URL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.login='$SONAR_CREDENTIAL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.modules=module1' >> sonar-project.properties

echo 'module1.sonar.projectName='M1_C1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.projectKey='M1_C1.sonar$COMPONENT_KEY >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.sources='$SRC_DIR >> sonar-project.properties
```

Now when I run the jobs on all components, under M1 project in sonar dashboard it creates M1_C1 component, but on next run, M1_C1 is removed and M1_C2 is added. Its like project is reset on every run.

I hope you guys understood my issue.

I want that all the successive should add the new modules without deleting older modules.

Is there any way to achieve the above in SonarQube.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to scan all sources together. It is impossible to push partial data and append it.

It means you can do something like this:

```
# create sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectKey='M1.sonar > sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectName='M1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectVersion=1.0' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.host.url='$SONAR_URL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.login='$SONAR_CREDENTIAL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.modules=module1,module2' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.projectName='M1_C1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.projectKey='M1_C1.sonar$COMPONENT_KEY >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.sources='$SRC_DIR >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.projectName='M2_C1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.projectKey='M2_C1.sonar$COMPONENT_KEY2 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.sources='$SRC_DIR2 >> sonar-project.properties
# execute scanner
sonar-scanner
```

but you cannot do something like this:

```
# create sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectKey='M1.sonar > sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectName='M1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectVersion=1.0' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.host.url='$SONAR_URL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.login='$SONAR_CREDENTIAL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.modules=module1' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.projectName='M1_C1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.projectKey='M1_C1.sonar$COMPONENT_KEY >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module1.sonar.sources='$SRC_DIR >> sonar-project.properties
# execute scanner
sonar-scanner

# create sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectKey='M1.sonar > sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectName='M1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.projectVersion=1.0' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.host.url='$SONAR_URL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.login='$SONAR_CREDENTIAL >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'sonar.modules=module2' >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.projectName='M2_C1 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.projectKey='M2_C1.sonar$COMPONENT_KEY2 >> sonar-project.properties
echo 'module2.sonar.sources='$SRC_DIR2 >> sonar-project.properties
# execute scanner
sonar-scanner
```

Because second execution of the scanner overwrites all data.

Comment: hi agabrys, thanks for the reply, but I cannot scan all sources at once as the job runs on individual components.

Comment: It means you cannot group them as one module. The answer to your question in your case `Is it possible to append new modules to existing SonarQube project?` is **no, it is impossible**.